# EREG expression for one or more first names separated by comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I somehow can't get this to work. I want at least one name but also the possibility to add more names separated by a comma and space.

This is what i got:

```
var exp_name2 = /^[A-Z]{1}[a-z-]*[,\s][A-Z]{1}[a-z-]$/;
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so you're wanting it to be like this: Name, nAme lastname,NAME

```
[a-zA-Z\s]*(?:,?[\s]?)?
```

Selects either lowercase or uppercase letters until it hits a `,` or a space, then repeats.

Otherwise: Name, Name, Name

```
[A-Z][a-z\s]*(?:,\s)?
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that should work. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/bZy5Q/1/